# Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to create a Table View outlet and immediately after I create it, when I check the outlets for the view, I get the yellow triangle and the app doesn't build. I gives me the `NSException`. I just upgraded to xcode 7.2, but it was working with the old version.

[image]

Comment: So what's the class name and what's it a subclass of?

Comment: I'm new to iOS and this is an intro tutorial, so I apologize if I'm not clear. But the table view I'm dragging and trying to create an outlet for is the first view in the view controller

Comment: The classname is `MoviesViewController`